# Wake PC from Xbox One controller works only once

Tags: windows-11, sleep

I'm trying to get my Windows 11 PC to wake from sleep using an Xbox One controller with a 1713 wireless adapter. The adapter works when I try to wake the PC immediately after putting it to sleep after pairing the controller and adapter, but when I try to wake the PC a long while after putting it to sleep, or if I try to wake it, put it back to sleep, and wake it again, both fail to work. Instead, the controller connects to seemingly nothing, with the guide button staying lit after a few blinks.

I've tried messing with just about every relevant setting I can find, between bios wake-on-lan, wake-on-usb, and USB power delivery, power management for the adapter and the case's usb hub, and USB selective suspend. The only real thing of note is that disabling the PC from turning off the adapter to save power grays out the allow device to wake PC option, and the adapter no longer turns the PC on regardless of whether it's enabled or not. Part of the problem might be that the controller is one of the later bluetooth-enabled models, so could be circumventing the adapter somehow.

None of these problems happen with my keyboard-and-mouse adapter - they wake the PC from sleep far too easily, in fact, which is part of why I want to use a controller instead. I've also tried wake-on-lan from my phone, and it can wake the PC, but it also seems to wake the PC at random, even with it set to only wake with a magic packet. After spending over $30 between the 1713 adapter and the newer model adapter I bought first that doesn't wake the PC at all, it'd be nice to have a more convenient way to turn on the PC without getting up, so I'd be interested in any advice anyone has to make the PC consistently wake from the controller.